# Why can I only press my play/pause buttons once in my android notification?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-intent, notifications

I've built a notification for my media app that will let the user play/pause their audio. But right now they can only press the button in the notification once.. How can I get it so the user can continuously hit the play/pause button?

I've tried to just make a new notification in my activity as a way to just refresh the information but that hasn't gotten me much results yet.

Building out the notification

```
public void Init(DabPlayer Player, bool IntegrateWithLockScreen)
        {
            player = Player;
            var mSession = new MediaSessionCompat(Application.Context, "MusicService");
            mSession.SetFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FlagHandlesMediaButtons | MediaSessionCompat.FlagHandlesTransportControls);
            var controller = mSession.Controller;
            var description = GlobalResources.playerPodcast;

            if (IntegrateWithLockScreen)
            {
                /* SET UP LOCK SCREEN */
                CreateNotificationChannel();

                player.EpisodeDataChanged += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    // Set up an intent so that tapping the notifications returns to this app:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity));
                    Intent playPauseIntent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(SecondActivity));
                    // Create a PendingIntent; we're only using one PendingIntent (ID = 0):
                    const int pendingIntentId = 0;
                    const int firstPendingIntentId = 1;
                    PendingIntent firstPendingIntent =
                        PendingIntent.GetActivity(Application.Context, firstPendingIntentId, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                        PendingIntent.GetActivity(Application.Context, pendingIntentId, playPauseIntent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

                    // Build the notification:
                    var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(Application.Context, CHANNEL_ID)
                                  .SetStyle(new Android.Support.V4.Media.App.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                                            .SetMediaSession(mSession.SessionToken)
                                            .SetShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1))
                                  .SetVisibility(NotificationCompat.VisibilityPublic)
                                  .SetContentIntent(firstPendingIntent) // Start up this activity when the user clicks the intent.
                                  .SetDeleteIntent(MediaButtonReceiver.BuildMediaButtonPendingIntent(Application.Context, PlaybackState.ActionStop))
                                  .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.app_icon) // This is the icon to display
                                  .AddAction(Resource.Drawable.ic_media_pause_dark, "Pause", pendingIntent)
                                  .AddAction(Resource.Drawable.ic_media_play_dark, "Next", pendingIntent)
                                  .SetContentText(GlobalResources.playerPodcast.EpisodeTitle)
                                  .SetContentTitle(GlobalResources.playerPodcast.ChannelTitle);

                    // Finally, publish the notification:
                    var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(Application.Context);
                    notificationManager.Notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.Build());                   
                };

                player.EpisodeProgressChanged += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
                {

                };


            }
```

And then my activity looks like this

```
[Activity]
    public class SecondActivity : Activity
    {
        DabPlayer player = GlobalResources.playerPodcast;
        EpisodeViewModel Episode;
        DroidDabNativePlayer droid = new DroidDabNativePlayer();
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            if (player.IsReady)
            {
                if (player.IsPlaying)
                {
                    player.Pause();
                    droid.Init(player, true);
                }
                else
                {
                    player.Play();
                    droid.Init(player, true);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (player.Load(Episode.Episode))
                {
                    player.Play();
                    droid.Init(player, true);
                }
                else
                {
                    //DisplayAlert("Episode Unavailable", "The episode you are attempting to play is currently unavailable. Please try again later.", "OK");
                }

            }

            Finish();
        }
    }
```

I also want to just go down to one button and have it switch between showing pause and play depending on the state if anyone wants to point me in the right direction for that as well.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean they can only press play once? what happens the 2nd time? What was the result of you refreshing the notification?

Comment: It doesn't respond to a second click event. Nothing happens after they click it a second time. 

Refreshing the notification didn't allow me to be able click the buttons again.

Comment: Right now there's 2 buttons there doing the same thing, just look different, but if I click on one of them I can't even click on the other. It seems to just kill the button interactions after the first event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent

PendingIntents with `OneShot` can only be used once.

> Flag indicating that this PendingIntent can be used only once.
>   If set, after send() is called on it, it will be automatically canceled for you and any future attempt to send through it will fail.

Either use a `PendingIntent` with no flags (to allow the user to press the button multiple times and send multiple intents) or use a new id everytime you requests a `PendingIntent` to allow for the button to be pressed once each time you update the notification.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank You!